# Angular Change path and router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Please tell me how can I go from this component http://localhost:4200/(letone:one) to another component using a link, for example here http://localhost:4200/(lettwo:two)

I tried to do it like this

```
    <button [routerLink]="['../', { outlets: { 'lettwo' : 'two' } }]">Button Two</button>
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular scenario when using different outlets it should be:

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet name="letone"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="lettwo"></router-outlet>
```

**app-router.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'one', component: PageOneComponent, outlet: 'letone' },
      { path: 'two', component: PageTwoComponent, outlet: 'lettwo' },
    ],
  },
];
```

**page-one.component.html**

```
<p>Page one - 1</p>
<button [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { letone: null, lettwo : 'two' } }]">to Two</button>
```

**page-two.component.html**

```
<p>Page two - 2</p>
<button [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { letone : 'one', lettwo: null } }]">to One</button>
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#createUrlTree

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-be5nd8

Comment: I mean this https://angular.io/api/router/Route#componentless-routes

Comment: @MarieSpeak maybe you can provide your router configuration so it will be more clear what is the structure of it?

Comment: Oh sure. Here is https://github.com/MyTestPerson/Router-Path

Comment: @MarieSpeak please look updated answer